# How to call an extension class

Tags: c#

I try to call an extension class in a `Form`, for a TreeView, the class is :

```
namespace Extension
{
    public static class ExtensionClass
    {
        public static List<TreeNode> Parents(this TreeNode node)
        {
            var parents = new List<TreeNode>();
            TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
            while (parent != null) ;
            {
                parents.Add(parent);
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            return parents;
        }

        public static void CheckChildren(this TreeNode node)
        {
            if (!node.Checked)
                return;

            foreach (TreeNode node1 in node.Nodes)
            {
                node1.Checked = true;
                node1.CheckChildren();
            }
        }

        public static TreeNode CheckParentsAndChildren(this TreeNode node)
        {
            TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
            while (parent != null) ;
            {
                parent.Checked = true;
                parent.CheckChildren();
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            return parent;
        }
    }
}
```

and in `Form` I added `using Extension;`. But this code doesn't work, nothing happened, and by the way I have for this code 2 Warnings :"possible mistake empty statement".
My question is how I can call this class ?? I must add something in Form where I have :

```
using Extension;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: `while (parent != null) ;` loops forever without doing anything. Remove the semicolon.

Comment: I don't see any uses of the extension methods in the `Form2`.  So what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @poke: not quite true, if `node.Parent` is `null` you are lucky.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That’s an irrelevant edge case. Arguing that way will only add to the problem.

Comment: I have created a treeView in Form 2 and the extension class is for that View

Comment: @poke: my comment was not really meant to be taken seriously.

Comment: @PopDaniela So are you asking how to call the extension methods?  If so, then Oliver has your answer.  If not, you need to be more clear about the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use these extension methods as if they were methods of the `TreeNode` class

```
private bool _checking;

private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_checking && e.Node.Checked) {
        _checking = true;
        try {
            e.Node.CheckParentsAndChildren();
        } finally {
            _checking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is only [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). The extension method call above is equivalent to:

```
ExtensionClass.CheckParentsAndChildren(e.Node);
```

---

---

Your code has logical problems.
In `CheckParentsAndChildren` you are not only checking all the parents of a node, but also all the children of all these parents. The effect is that you are checking the whole tree!

`CheckParentsAndChildren` should only check the children of the current node

```
public static void CheckParentsAndChildren(this TreeNode node)
{
    node.CheckChildren(); // Check children of current node only.
    TreeNode parent = node.Parent;
    while (parent != null) // ; <-- this semicolon was the problem!!
    {
        parent.Checked = true;
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
}
```

And also this method should probably have a `void` return type.

---

Further you should use the `AfterCheck` event (occurs after setting or clearing the check-mark) instead of `AfterSelect` event (occurs after selecting the node) and test whether the user is checking or unchecking.

There is also the problem that `AfterCheck` is triggered when you check the node programmatically as well. Therefore I introduced a [guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) `_checking` that is set before checking nodes in code in order to prevent `treeView1_AfterCheck` being called repeatedly. In order to be sure that the guard will be reset after the job is done, even if an exception occurs, I have put the code in a [try-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) statement.

Comment: if a parent is checked then automatically all children to be check, and if a child is checked automatically the parent to be check

Comment: Yes, but you are walking up the chain of all parents until you reach the root of the tree, and if you call `CheckChildren` on this one, this will check the whole tree recursively: `parent.Checked = true;
                parent.CheckChildren();
                parent = parent.Parent; ...`.

Comment: Well, I have. See my code example: `node.CheckChildren();` is called before the while-loop and the loop only checks the parents.

Comment: You had a semicolon after the "while" (that I erroneously copied from you code). Therefore the loop only consisted of an empty statement and did execute the following statement block. The `Parents` method also has the same problem. Instead of `while (codition) ; { ... }`, write `while (codition) { ... }`

Comment: I changed my code example to use the `AfterCheck` event and added an explanation.

Comment: You can download a working VS 2013 solution here: http://cysoft.ch/Sources/HowToCallAnExtensionClass.zip

Answer (score 0):

Sure nothing happens because you never call those extension-methods. Only because they are there within your code does not mean they get executed. Thus within your event-handler for the tree add the relevant code:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.CheckParentsAndChildren();
    e.Node.CheckChildren();
    var parents = e.Node.Parents();
}
```

Also have a look at [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `e.Node`.

Comment: it doesn't work, nothing happens . Is possible as my class to not work properly ??

Comment: Have you already corrected the error mentioned within the comments with the infinite while-loop mentioned from poke? If so what ARE the errors?

Comment: doesn't exists the errors, just the fact that the code don't do anything

Comment: Have you tried to debug a bit? Nothing happens could mean everything from program being shut down to program is in infinite loop.

Comment: nothing happens means : when I check a parent, children are not all automatically check, and when I check a child the parent are not automatically check